# How to setup Lighttpd as a proxy for cross-site requests?

Tags: proxy, lighttpd

I want to setup my lighttpd server to proxy some requests (for ex. RSS requests) to other domains so i can fetch data using javascript. For example i'd like to fetch Atmo feed from internal Redmine (say http://code.internal.acme) to developer dashboard (say http://dashboard.internal.acme). I'd like to fetch it using JavaScript but i cant use something like JSONP and i don't want to use Flash for that.
Currently i have this in my lighttpd.conf

`proxy.server = ( "/http-bind/" => ( ( "host" => "10.0.100.52", "port" => 5280 ) ) )`

This way i can connect to our internal jabber server via Javascript. But i want more generic way... Something like

`proxy.server = ( "/proxy/{1}" => ( ( "url" => {1} ) ) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no way to di this. So i simply write "proxy" with Python for that.

Thanks everybody for your ideas...